# How does a monster's AC from AD&D/2e relate to AC in D&D 5th Edition?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, adnd-2e, conversion, armor-class

I want to adapt several creatures from AD&D/2e so I can use them in 5e. 
Is there an easy way to translate **Armour Class** from AD&D/2e to AC in 5e?

I'm looking for a formula if possible. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It isn't quite so easy given that AC calculations have changed between editions as well as underlying philosophies (eg. there are no +5 weapons in the core 5th edition rules and no +5 armor either).

AD&D AC more or less worked like this though, an AC of 10 equated to you having no armor on at all (DEX was not applied in that edition). An AC of 0 equated to you having the best non-magical armor and shield on.

In 5th edition, no armor and no DEX modifier means an AC of 10. So a simple method of converting AD&D AC to 5th edition would be:

5th Ed. AC = 20 - AD&D AC.

So an AC of 5 in AD&D would equal an AC of 15 in 5th edition. I would suggest however that you look for other creatures that have made the jump between editions and have the same AC as the monsters you wish to convert. Then check what the 5th edition AC is for them and use that.

Comment: that is a really helpful answer. Thank you